# How can I evaluate percentage with Rails / Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

in application.helper I was trying to do this.
However it always get 0. Why?

I want something like 37% 49% 98%
Always integer. no float

```
def evaluate(number_of_people)
    percentage = ((number_of_people / 10000) * 100 ).truncate
    "<div class='percentage'>Percentage is #{percentage}%</div>".html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dividing by an integer, so the result of 3000 / 10000 will be 0.

Divide by 10000.0 instead to force decimal aritmatic.

So change this:

```
percentage = ((number_of_people / 10000) * 100 ).truncate
```

To this:

```
percentage = ((number_of_people / 10000.0) * 100 ).to_i
```

If your denominator (the 10000 value in this case) is a variable you can use to_f to cast it as a float before dividing.

Comment: 3000 / 10000 has to be 0.3 though:(

Comment: But 0.3 as an integer is 0. If you divide by an integer, your result will be an integer.

Comment: How can I get something like 75% easily?

Comment: percentage itself always has to be integer.

Comment: You can cast it back to an integer with to_i, but you need to have a decimal before you multiply by 100.